# Возникла потребность добавить в си код с++ код, решил перекомпилировать си код с++ компиляором, но malloc выдает ошибку

Tags: c++, c, qt, gcc

Возникла потребность добавить в си код с++ код, решил перекомпилировать си код с++ компиляором, но malloc выдает ошибку: `/home/anton/Programming/test1111/main.cpp:6: ошибка: cannot initialize a variable of type 'char *' with an rvalue of type 'void *'`. Использую qt + gcc. Как это исправить ?

Comment: Скорее всего нужно явное преобразование. Примерно так: `char* ptr = (char*)malloc(...`

Comment: "Я тут немного повозился с движком машины, и теперь он постукивает. Как это исправить?" Скажите, хоть кто-то в здравом уме, не видя, что вы делали с движком, ответит? "Я выпил из одной бутылочки жидкость, и теперь у меня болит живот" - врач будет заочно, не видя, что за бутылочка и что там за содержимое, лечить? Ну почему все считают, что вопрос "исправьте ситуацию, а какую - не ваше дело" - это нормально?!

Comment: @Harry, человек выше уже ответил мне

Comment: Сожалею, что вы так и не поняли, насколько неверно поступили, а человек уверил вас в том, что это не случайность, и что задавать вопросы надо именно так - не читая https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, не думая... Очень жаль, что это вас ничему не научило - судя по вашему мне ответу.

Comment: Не самая удачная идея...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данная ошибка возникает из-за различий правил преобразования указателей `void *` в указатели других типов. В языке C *неявное* преобразование указателей `void *` в указатели на другие объектные типы разрешено, тогда как в C++ такое преобразование не предусмотрено. Однако в обоих языках такое преобразование разрешается произвести явно:

```
void * p1 = 0;
char * p2 = p1;       //C - ok, C++ - ошибка
char * p3 = (char*)p1;//C - ok, C++ - ok
```

Функция `malloc` как раз возвращает указатель типа `void *`, и в вашем коде результат функции присваивается указателю типа `char *`, что и приводит к ошибке, если нет явного преобразования типа:

```
char * p1 = malloc(size);        //C - ok, C++ - ошибка
char * p2 = (char *)malloc(size);//C - ok, C++ - ok
```

Способ с явным преобразованием является совместимым как с C, так и с C++, но это не значит, что это единственная проблема с которой вы можете столкнуться, если будете компилировать C-код компилятором C++.