# Зачем нужно писать указатель в скобках перед вызовом функции?

Tags: c++, c

Я наткнулся на следующий пример в учебнике:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 

int main() 
{ 

    // This pointer will hold the 
    // base address of the block created 
    int* ptr; 
    int n, i; 

    // Get the number of elements for the array 
    n = 5; 
    printf("Enter number of elements: %d\n", n); 

    // Dynamically allocate memory using malloc() 
    ptr = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int)); 

    return 0; 
}
```

Вроде бы все логично, функция malloc() выделяет память под 5 целых чисел, но перед этим идет `(int*)`, зачем это нужно и что оно делает, как это называется? Я ещё не встречал подобной записи, когда перед вызовом функции было бы что-то кроме самой переменной.

А ещё я попробовал записать вместо:

```
ptr = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
```

Так:

```
ptr = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
```

И никакой ошибки не произошло, я могу работать с этим указателем (ptr) и тд. Зачем же там `(int*)`?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1096325/Возникла-потребность-добавить-в-си-код-с-код-решил-перекомпилировать-си-код-с/1097659#1097659

Comment: Это *приведение типа* требуется в С++, но не в С. В C такое приведение выполняется самим компилятором; в С++ его надо указывать явно. Если учебник по С++ - автор прав, если по С - такое приведение - "масло масляное", и, вероятно, автор сам либо работает на С++ и воткнул по привычке, либо... :)